# Project Trigger Not working

Tags: google-apps-script, zapier

I'm using Cognito forms to collect information and then using Zapier to pass this information to my google spreadsheet database. I have found that my scripts in google spreadsheets do not trigger the way I would expect.

This one:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ColCR = 96;  // Column Number of "CR"
  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColCR) {
    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    var adjacent = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColCR+1);
    var adjacentv = adjacent.getValue();
    var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-7", "M/dd/yy', 'h:mm a"); 
     switch (adjacentv) {
      case "":
     adjacent.setValue("("+timestamp+")"+" "+state);
     changedRange.clearContent();
        break;
      default:
     adjacent.setValue(adjacentv+"\n"+"("+timestamp+")"+" "+state);
     changedRange.clearContent();
        break;
      }
  } 
}
```

Works fine when a user edits the spreadsheet cell directly but not when Zapier updates the cell. It also works on several different types of triggers when the spreadsheet is modified by a user. What is the difference between editing the spreadsheet directly vs having an app like Zapier edit the form? Can I write a script that would see an edit by an app like Zapier?

This one:

```
function Timestamp() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var comments = cell.getComment();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-7", "M/dd/yy', 'h:mm a    ");
   Newline works in msgBox, but not in Note.
  comments = comments + "Mod: " + formattedDate; 
 Browser.msgBox(comments);
 cell.setComment(comments);
}
```

Works fine when a user edits a cell and is triggered by a On Change trigger and also works when Zapier updates a cell but when Zapier updates more then one cell in a row it only puts the comment in the first cell in the range. How would I modify the script so that it triggers on every change to every cell and not just the range?

Im sure it has something to do with how Zapier is interacting with my spreadsheet but I don't understand how Zapier edits are any different than user edits?

Thanks for any suggestions or recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this issue as well, and in the end came to the conclusion that the Zapier action uses the API to update the Google Sheet, thus not triggering the trigger.  Details available here in Google's documentation of Simple Triggers:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/